# Differences between Facebook's Fan, Subscriber, and Like?

Tags: facebook

I've heard that Facebook is now adding a new feature called **Subscribers**.

What is it, and how is it different from being a **Fan** of something, or even **Liking** something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribers are people who want to follow your public posts but are not friends. They will be able to read what you post as public on your personal profile just like a follower on Twitter or someone who adds you to a circle in Google+.

Fans are people who follow or like a business, brand or product page.

> #### [Should I create a Page or allow subscribers to get my public updates?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=203141666415461)
>
> If your goal is to share updates from your personal profile with a broader audience, allowing subscribers is a good option. When you allow subscribers, anyone can subscribe and get your public updates in News Feed, even if you're not friends on Facebook.

You can have an unlimited number of people subscribing to you, but are limited to 5000 subscriptions you want to follow, just like friends.

Simply put, a subscriber follows/likes a person while a fan likes/follows a brand/business/product.